# Using Fragments, Tabs and Lists in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an ArrayList of items in the activity that I would like to rearrange and view when I click on the different tabs. I have fragments created for each tab and I already have the rearrangement methods. I do not know how to access the Collection from the activity and pass it into the fragment for arrangement. What is the best way for this;

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity, create a method that return your Collection object. 
e.g

```
public ArrayList<String> getCollection()
{
   return ur_Collection;
}
```

And In your Fragment use method

```
(TypeCast_to_your_Activity)getActivity().getCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have an interface which the `Activity` implements and the `Fragment` uses.

```
public interface MyInterface{
    List<Object> getList();
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface{
    @Override
    public List<Object> getList(){
        return myList;
    }
}


public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    MyInterface myInterface;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context){
        myInterface = (MyInterface) context;
        // now you can call myInterface.getList() anywhere in your fragment
    }
}
```

Comment: in this solution the getList method in the Activity is supposed to contain the code required to return a variable called myList. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Custom Adapter extending from  FragmentStatePagerAdapter for view pager that will hold the data. Inside your Custom adapter, pass the data to your fragments in getItem like this :

`

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        YourFragment f = new YourFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("data", filteredList); // get filteredList from list passed to adapter based on your rearrangement method
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
```

`

Then inside your fragment, in OnViewCreated(), you can get the passed data as Arguments, and use it as intended.